# Updating default Ionic App icon with your own icon

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I recently attempted to follow the instructions offered on Ionic's website on how to update the icon and the splash screen for both a hybrid app. The link: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html However when I followed the instructions the app only updated the icons of the android version of the app. I am assuming this was the case because I did not include the compiled ios version in the ionic project. However, when I submit the beta app to the Google Play Store the app downloads with the default ionic app icon. When I review the resources folder, the android icons are updated.  Also looking at the config.xml file shows the following configuration for the android platform:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
```

Has anyone encountered such a problem and can you advise me what you did to correct the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm checking a config file of a project of mine.
For android, there seems to be an extra entry outside the `<platform name="android">` property.

So like this:
`<platform name="android">`
`...`
`</platform>`
`<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>`

What happens if you add the last entry as above explained,